# What are Hax powers and why are they considered Hax?

Tags: powers

I researched Hax and found to many varying accounts, from "powers that are strong for no reason" to powers that are "overpowered" to powers that "negate/cheat/bypass physical abilities." What is the actual definition of Hax powers?

Comment: Hax is just a humorous spelling of hacks, which in turn is a complaint long used in video games to refer to players who are doing so well that they supposedly must be using prohibited game modifications (hacks). This can be generalized to any other situation where someone appears to have an unfair advantage by cheating.  The question does not really have much to do with science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Adamant so how would that apply to supepowers? The term is Hax _powers_

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about Sci-Fi or Fantasy within the [scope defined in the Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This might be on-topic in [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). If you're gonna ask this there, tag the question with [terminology].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the terminology varies, but [the Vs. Battles wiki](https://vsbattles.fandom.com/wiki/Hax) defines it as:

> Hax is a catch-all term for abilities that can be used to ignore/bypass one or more of a target's statistics, rendering them irrelevant.

Basically, it's the equivalent of the person playing Cops and Robbers who states that they have a bulletproof suit, so all the bullets bounce off (or the guy who counters that they have an anti-bulletproof suit-gun), or that they have a gun which can't miss, so they hit everything they aim at, except that it simply works that way in-universe.

To provide an example from a specific universe, in the *Worm* universe, [Flechette](https://worm.fandom.com/wiki/Flechette) has the ability to make an object she touches bypass any defenses when she hits, allowing her to ignore armor and damage seemingly invulnerable opponents. Another from *Worm* is [Contessa](https://worm.fandom.com/wiki/Contessa), who knows exactly how to succeed in whatever she plans to do by knowing all of the steps (although there are some entities and powers that she simply does not get answers when she asks for the steps).

Comment: So it's just a really good superpower

Comment: @rakob1203: Specifically, it's one that bypasses the normal rules. It's being able to move your checkers pieces as if they were chess pieces.

Comment: Oh, so a superpower which violates normal limits. Got it.